# consolas font splits words at the end of a line

Tags: microsoft-word

I am using a code editor called RStudio. It can produce a .docx output of the code that looks fairly nice for publishing. However the .docx document uses the consolas font. In Word, it splits words at the end of a line. 
So it may do something like this

For consistency, we should choose whe

ther to write W1 first or to write X first.

I can't figure out how to fix this in Word. Does anyone have a suggestion? I tried changing the font but that does not fix the problem.
 I checked for line-breaks and it does not seem to have them because when I put the insertion bar to the left of the t as suggested and press backspace the e disappears

Comment: Surely you fix this in Word by removing the line-break which is inserted (position the cursor before the *t* of *ther* and press backspace). To fix the root cause it's likely that RStudio needs to change: it may be a simple setting checkbox; it could be a software upgrade.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry I was not clear, I have about 3000 of these occurrences and so what I would like to find is some way to either search and replace or some way to use the "copy formatting" feature in Word.

Comment: Hi. Weclome to GDSE. This sounds like the lines have line breaks at the end. I don't think it has anything to do with the font as such.  Perhaps the fault is with the way the software is outputing the docx?  Could you perhaps try reaching out to the developers. It may be a bug.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome. I checked for line-breaks and it does not seem to have them because when I put the insertion bar to the left of the t as suggested and press backspace the e disappears.

Comment: Aha: thanks for trying that. That's important information which should really be added to the question itself.

Comment: Perhaps there's a character limit width set? I'm nto a huge Word user, but in some text editors you can set line to contain a maximum amount of characters. Once that max is hit a line feed is added regardless of what the characters actually represent.

Comment: Which version of Word are you using?  Mine always splits to a new line at the whitespace, never in the middle of a word.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem and it is indeed caused by the Consolas font in combination with paragraph justification, not by any manual line-breaks.

I've changed the justified style to left-aligned, and it no longer splits words at the end of the line. Try it yourself and see if it corrects the problem.